# Cannot swipe to unlock due to broken screen

Tags: lock-screens, broken-screen, touchscreen, locked-out

My Vortex tablet has a cracked screen and I'm not able to swipe up to open my home screen. How do I bypass that for a screen where I have to swipe up?

Comment: Connect a simple USB mouse to your phone and check if you get a mouse cursor.